# "Unable to connect to web server 'IIS Express'"

Tags: visual-studio-2015, visual-studio-2017, iis-express

.NET CORE 1.1 application, normally works and runs on localhost:5000.  Sometimes I start getting the title error, and then I have to reboot my machine.  I think I might have tracked it down somewhat to Docker now using port 5000.  So I stopped docker figured that would be it.  But I keep getting the same error.  Resource monitor shows that port 5000 is in use by pid 4 'System'.  I've killed the IIS processes and the port disappears.  Then when I run my app again I keep getting the same error.  I can restart VS (both 2015 and 2017) and use different ports, but I keep getting the error until I reboot.

Is there some way to recover from this without a reboot?

Comment: I assume this is a .NET Core 1.1 app. **Never say .NET 1.1 as that means .NET Framework 1.1 which is end of life**.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I was able to get it work doing the following:

- Close Visual Studio
- Delete the `.vs` directory *in the solution folder*
- Restart Visual Studio
- Change project to run on another port and debug it
- Stop Debugging and change port back to 5000, then restart

Answer (score 0):

In the Project properties, try changing the port number to something different:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After tried many options. Finally I have restarted my machine and it works.